# pandas: apply string function to groupby columns

Tags: python, pandas, apply, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe as follows,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'label':['first','second','first','first','second','second'],
               'first_text':['how is your day','the weather is nice','i am feeling well','i go to school','this is good','that is new'],
               'second_text':['today is warm','this is cute','i am feeling sick','i go to work','math is hard','you are old'],
               'third_text':['i am a student','the weather is cold','she is cute','ii am at home','this is bad','this is trendy']})
```

I would like to groupby columns based on the label column and apply type token ratio from [lexical richness](https://github.com/LSYS/LexicalRichness) library which is a function applied to strings. So far I have done the following,

```
df_lex =df.groupby('label')[['first_text','second_text','third_text']].agg(lambda x: LexicalRichness(' '.join(x.tolist()))).reset_index()
```

so now i need to apply the rttr function to each column. when I apply it to one column, i get the answer for that column as follows,

```
print(df_lex['first_text'].apply(lambda x: x.rttr))
#output 
#0    3.175426
#1    2.529822
```

but is there a way to apply it to all columns at once?

Comment: How about just adding it at the end of your first function: `df.groupby('label')[['first_text','second_text','third_text']].agg(lambda x: LexicalRichness(' '.join(x)).rttr).reset_index()`? (you don't need `.tolist()` here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```
df[['Col1','Col2']] = df[['Col1','Col2']].apply(f)
```

where f is your function.